# ffmpeg thumbnails: Every 2 seconds, generated at 0, 1, 3, 5 seconds

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to generate thumbnails from a piece of .mov video.  I want to get thumbnails every two seconds, and so, copying almost directly from https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video, I'm doing:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mov -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1/2 thumb%04d.jpg
```

This works, and gives me thumbnails, but they correspond to the images from the video at 0, 1, 3, 5, ... seconds.  I was expecting 0, 2, 4, 6, ... seconds; I'm not sure why there's an initial one second gap between thumbnails before it settles into making them every two seconds.

Is there a way to get them to come out at 0, 2, 4, 6... seconds, or is this just "how it works"?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not related to your problem but I had frame accurracy problems with the parameter "fps" in the past. Instead I used the "select" filter:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mov -vf "select='not(mod(n,50))',setpts='N/(25*TB)'" -f image2 thumb%04d.jpg
```

This should work fine for you as well if you're dealing with 25 fps movies.

Edit:

For NTSC, change the select filter to:

```
select='not(mod(n,60))',setpts='N/(30*TB)'"
```

and for cinema movies, change it to

```
select='not(mod(n,48))',setpts='N/(24*TB)'"
```

Basically it overrides the PTS (presentation timestamp) to the correct value and selects a frame everytime the frame number is a multiple of the value within the "Mod" function. This value must be equal to twice your framerate.

Forgive me for using the values for PAL by default, I use FFMPEG for broadcast purpose in Europe mainly :)

Comment: Hmm -- I tried this, and got images at 0, 1.62, 3.28, 4.95, 4.95 (yes, again), 6.61, 8.27, and 9.94.  In this test, I'm working with a video of my phone running a stopwatch for about 12 seconds; it starts as close to 0:00 as I was able to get, but is probably off by a frame or two, but not much more.  I'm also with @Jay about not understanding the command...

Comment: Hi, I've tried to explain it better. Let me know if it is still unclear! Sorry again for posting answer with PAL values only at first ;)

Comment: Aha -- very nice!  Then, use 90 for every 3 seconds, 120 for every 4 seconds, etc.  Thanks!

Comment: amazing so few people have found this answer useful - its awesome!